# CollapsingToolbarLayout without title animation

Tags: android, toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am working with `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.
I don't know any methods to pin title in Toolbar.

Is there any simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This solution works for me.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        app:titleEnabled="false"
        ...
>
```

Comment: It is good to know, that this attribute does not removes or hides the title when set to false. It just disables the animation of the title.

Comment: Cool, this also re-enabled the subtitle!

Comment: @roncsak Doesn't disable animation for me, it completely hides the title

Answer (score -1):

You have to set its title manually in code.

```
CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar =
              (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
      collapsingToolbar.setTitle("Title");
```