# CollapsingToolbar - How do I disable the title animation?

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm trying to display the title when the collapsing toolbar is Expanded or Collapsed. However in any of those states, the title always has a shifting animation:

[image]

How do I completely get rid of the animation and make the title stay in one position?

I've tried setting titleEnabled to false but that only disables title and not show it anymore

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35975029/11110509

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        app:titleEnabled="false"
        ...
>
```

**Edit1: My full layout:**
**___________________________________________________________________________**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
       android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@color/colorWhite">

      <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
          android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          app:contentScrim="@color/standardBlue"
          app:title="Title"
          app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

         <RelativeLayout
             android:id="@+id/activityprofile_topsection"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/activityprofile_coverpicture"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:background="@color/standardBlue" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/activityprofile_profilepicture"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
                android:background="@drawable/profile_picture_white_border" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/activityprofile_username"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/activityprofile_profilepicture"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Username"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlackFont"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

         </RelativeLayout>

         <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
             app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
             app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/activityprofile_backbutton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/actionBarItemBackground"
                android:padding="15dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_back_white_arrow" />
         </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

      </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

      <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">

         <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:icon="@drawable/icon_back_black_arrow" />

         <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:icon="@drawable/ic_heart" />
      </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

   </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


   <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
       android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

As soon as I add `app:titleEnabled="false"` the title disappears

Still can't get CollapsingToolbar's title animation to be disabled.

Comment: Have you tried to play around with the API and see if it helps you achieve what you'd like? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout

Otherwise I would say that you'd need to re-implement that using another API or a combination of different android framework parts.

Comment: Are you setting the title on a `Toolbar` or on a `CollapsingToolbarLayout`?

Comment: collapsingtoolbar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you could possibly do something incorrectly with your layouts. I checked this behaviour and when you add `app:titleEnabled="false"`, the title should stay in the same place without any animation.

**app:titleEnabled="true"** (or without this attribute)

[image]

**app:titleEnabled="false"**

[image]

As you can see, this is the behaviour you want to achieve. Below I added a skeleton of a layout, which should work correctly.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    >

  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
      android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@android:color/transparent"
      android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
      >

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:elevation="@dimen/toolbar_elevation"
        app:contentScrim="@color/colorWhite"
        app:titleEnabled="false"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        >

      <RelativeLayout
          android:id="@+id/it_could_be_any_layout"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="@drawable/profile_bg"
          android:scaleType="centerCrop"
          app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
          >

       <!-- Your content here -->
       
      </RelativeLayout>

      <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
          android:id="@+id/toolbarProfile"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
          app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
          app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
          />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

  <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="@color/colorWhite"
      app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
      >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <!-- Your RecyclerView here or even replace this LinearLayout -->
    </LinearLayout>

  </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I think that you should check again your implementation and play with `layout_behavior`, `app:layout_scrollFlags`, `collapseMode` attributes and so on. I hope you'll be able to fix this issue.

Comment: I posted my layout above. Everytime I add ```app:titleEnabled="false"``` the title just completely disappears. Where are you setting the title ```"Profile Fragment"```?

Comment: In the Fragment programatically, using `toolbar.setTitle("")`.

Comment: Your collapsing toolbar doesn't have the fading effect though

Comment: Please look one more time at gifs I posted. The fading effect is there. This is a default effect of `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.

Comment: After giving up, I tried it again and I finally got it to work 2 months later. This needs to be set ```app:titleEnabled="false"``` and the ```toolbar.setTitle(" ")``` needs to be the toolbar of the REGULAR TOOLBAR not the CollapsingToolbarTitle. Thats why the animation wasn't being disabled...